# How to use a .qpt made in another project?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I'm trying to make maps in print composer of several different projects. 
I would like the maps to look the same, just for different areas, so I tried to use the .qpt that I made in the first project in the second one, but GIS data doesn't display? I just get the legend, frame and scalebar from the first map to show?

I read the manual, but the problem is that I still don't understand how to update the map with the information showing in the second project's map canvas?

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by "the map doesn't display", the frame or the GIS data within the frame?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the GIS data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After loading the .qpt template the rectangular frame in which the map is supposed to be displayed will say "Map will be printed here" in an empty frame. If you click on the frame and view the Item Properties tab to the right, Changing the dropdown item from "Rectangle" to "Render" should render the current project's display in the frame.

If your projects are in different locations you will have to update the 'Extents' of your map object. Zoom/pan the main canvas to your data, from the Print Composer window, click on the Map Object. Click on the Item Properties tab and it's "Extents" tab. Click "Set to map canvas extent". The map object should now look like your main canvas

Comment: I tried your suggestion just now, but I don't get it to work? I changed to "render" and updated but the GIS data still doesn't display?

Comment: If your projects are in different locations you will have to update the 'Extents' of your map object. Zoom/pan the main canvas to your data, from the Print Composer window, click on the Map Object. Click on the Item Properties tab and it's "Extents" tab. Click "Set to map canvas extent". The map object should now look like your main canvas

Comment: That worked! I clicked "Set map to canvas extent" and the map I wanted appeared on the canvas. Please update your answer with the information in your last comment, and I will set it as my accepted answer.